# Use renderText() to convert back slash is not working

Tags: r, shiny

I want to convert windows backslash to forward slash in R. Here is my example code in R, and it works:

```
path <- r"(C:\Users\wang\Documents\folder\file.txt)"
path
[1] "C:\\Users\\wang\\Documents\\folder\\file.txt"
```

When I add the code in shiny, it doesn't work. I don't know how to solve it.

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  textInput("path", "Enter the file path:"),
  textOutput("path"),
    )

server = function(input, output) {

  output$path <- renderText({r"(input$path)"}) ## here is not working
  }


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The code you’ve shown simply doesn’t attempt to perform any conversion. In fact, it displays the literal string `input$path` no the *value* of the input.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph The code works in R >4.0. You can see the output that works.

Comment: No, the code does *not* work.

Comment: I see what you mean, Thanks. How can I convert it in shiny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `stringr`:

```
library(shiny)
library(rebus)
library(stringr)

ui = fluidPage(
  textInput("path", "Enter the file path:"),
  textOutput("path"),
)

server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$path <- renderText({
    
    str_replace_all(input$path, BACKSLASH, BACKSLASH %R% BACKSLASH)
    
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. I am curious to know why `r"(input$path)"` does not work?

Comment: @Wang Again: what do you expect `r"(input$path)"` to actually do? You seem to think that it performs some specific function. But it doesn’t: it’s just a regular string, and it is *exactly* identical to writing, in R code, `"input$path"`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph if your run  r"(C:\Users\wang\Documents\folder\file.txt)" directly in R. it works.

Comment: @Wang You are merely printing a *string literal*. Not a variable. Furthermore, you’re not seeing the *value* printed but an approximation of its *syntax*. Try putting the string inside `message()` or `writeLines()` to see what it actually looks like: you’ll find that there are *single* backslashes, and that the quotes `"…"` are gone. — By contrast, printing a string directly in the R terminal will show you the string like you’d have it in R source code: surrounded by `"…"`, and with visible escape sequences. And, to clarify: this is always like this, and unrelated to Shiny.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simpler way in case someone else needs it.

```
library(shiny)
chartr0 <- function(x) chartr('\\','/', x) ## define a convert function

ui = fluidPage(
  textInput("path", "Enter the file path:"),
  textOutput("path"),
)

server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$path <- renderText({
    chartr0(input$path)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```